Azure pipelines conditional insertion for GIT tags
i want to create pipeline that will show prod stage only for tags. I mark tags as v1.0, v1.1 etc. I developed yaml like this:
resources:
  repositories:
    - repository: templates
      type: git
      name: templates
      ref: refs/tags/v0.1

trigger:
- main

pr:
- main

stages:
- template: templates/infra-terraform-deploy.yml@templates
  parameters:


- template: templates/infra-terraform-deploy.yml@templates
  parameters:


- ${{ if startsWith( variables['Build.SourceBranch'], 'refs/tags/' ) }}:
  - template: templates/infra-terraform-deploy.yml@templates
    parameters:



But unfortunately, last stage is always not present in my pipeline.
How to construct yaml pipeline in Azure Devops that will show last stage only for tags that starts with v letter? Or have pattern vX.Y.Z ?

- ${{ if startsWith( variables['Build.SourceBranch'], 'refs/tags/vX.Y.Z' ) }}: does this work ?

@wenbo didnt try to be honest. Looking for a solution to my problem

So the self repo of the pipeline also has tags like v1.0; and you don't want to run the last stage in infra-terraform-deploy.yml@templates using the code other than from such tags, right?

@AlvinZhao-MSFT yes indeed. In my Main repo i have a pipeline and i want to run last stage only when pipeline is run from a tag with the name v1.0 so indeed, i want to have a pattern that last stage will be run only for patter vX.Z.Y when i can set minor and major versions (and patches). Is it possible? It is possible for branch name starting with release but i want to use tags in this repo instead of release branches

Thanks for the confirmation. Let me have a test and come back to you with what I can find.

Update
As per the further discussions on the requirement to automatically extract the version from the tag name when the pipeline is using the source on the condition of startsWith( variables['Build.SourceBranch'], 'refs/tags/v' ), you may test with the updated YAML pipeline below.
It will first split the version together with majorVersion minorVersion and patchVersion from Build.SourceBranch; and then will evaluate if patchVersion is an empty string to decide whether to remove the Prod stage or not.
Still, we need to be cautious about the naming pattern when creating new tags, as there could be cases passing the evaluation and we are so limited by the default Expressions that can be only used at Compile time.
resources:
  repositories:
    - repository: templates
      type: git
      name: templates
      ref: refs/tags/v0.1

trigger:
- main

pr:
- main

variables:
- ${{ if startsWith( variables['Build.SourceBranch'], 'refs/tags/v' ) }}:
  - name: arraySplitedSourceBranch
    value: ${{ convertToJson(split(variables['Build.SourceBranch'], 'v')) }}
    # Extract version from Build.SourceBranch
  - name: version
    value: ${{ split(variables['Build.SourceBranch'], 'v')[1] }}
  - name: majorVersion
    value: ${{ split(variables['version'], '.')[0]}}
  - name: minorVersion
    value: ${{ split(variables['version'], '.')[1]}}
  - name: patchVersion
    value: ${{ split(variables['version'], '.')[2]}}

stages:
- template: templates/infra-terraform-deploy.yml@templates
  parameters:
    stageName: Dev

- template: templates/infra-terraform-deploy.yml@templates
  parameters:
    stageName: QA

- ${{ if and( startsWith( variables['Build.SourceBranch'], 'refs/tags/v' ), ne(variables['patchVersion'], '') ) }}:
  - template: templates/infra-terraform-deploy.yml@templates
    parameters:
      stageName: Prod




Based on your description, you may test to modify the pipeline YAML definition file in each tag with the sample contents below.
resources:
  repositories:
    - repository: templates
      type: git
      name: templates
      ref: refs/tags/v0.1

trigger:
- main

pr:
- main

parameters:
  - name: majorVersion
    type: number
    default: 1
  - name: minorVersion
    type: number
    default: 0
  - name: patchVersion
    type: number
    default: 0

variables:
  - name: tagName
    value: ${{ format('refs/tags/v{0}.{1}.{2}', parameters.majorVersion, parameters.minorVersion, parameters.patchVersion) }}

stages:
- template: templates/infra-terraform-deploy.yml@templates
  parameters:
    stageName: Dev

- template: templates/infra-terraform-deploy.yml@templates
  parameters:
    stageName: QA

- ${{ if eq( variables['Build.SourceBranch'], variables['tagName'] ) }}:
  - template: templates/infra-terraform-deploy.yml@templates
    parameters:
      stageName: Prod



The reason that we need to make sure the YAML definition files in each tag contains the modified contents, is because when selecting the tag/branch to run the pipeline, it also switches to use that .yml definition in the selected tag/branch to run the pipeline. For example, if the pipeline .yml file in v1.0 tag remains unchanged or say it contains your expression ${{ if startsWith( variables['Build.SourceBranch'], 'refs/tags/' ) }}:, the condition evaluation will pass and insert the Prod stage, which is not expected based on your requirement.

I really like your approach, any chance that pulling version can ba autometed? Do we really need parameters on top of tag name?

Oh, I understand what you mean. Let me do a further test.

Hi @michasaucer, Thanks for your time and sharing. It took me a while as my tests required some operations to modify the syntax and add tags for each attempt. I have shared an updated sample for your reference and hope the information helps.
